# Same value for both Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, html.textboxfor

I am new to Asp.Net and the Razor markup I need some help please,

I have two Html.TextBoxFor using the same property to store the value, I inserting text on my first TextBoxFor, so I was expecting that the same value would appear on the second Html.TextBoxFor.

I though this could be possible using the same property, and I wouldn't need Javascript to affect the text of the second TextBoxFor.

```
//Here is my first TextBoxFor

@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DeliveryNote.Shipment.SenderData.PtzipCode4, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100%" })



//Here is my second TextBoxFor, as you can see they are using the same property PtzipCode4

@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DeliveryNote.Shipment.SenderData.PtzipCode4, new { @class = "form-control",  @style = "width:100%" })

//I even tried using the Value tag as you can see below, but the value kept it zero value

Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DeliveryNote.Shipment.SenderData.PtzipCode4, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.DeliveryNote.Shipment.SenderData.PtzipCode4,  @style = "width:100%" })
```

When I write on a TextBox the model property is not changed? do I need to post the information back to the controller? I though this controllers (TextBoxFor) worked on server side.

Thanks a lot for your help, I would like a brief explanation why this doesn't work and how can I achieve it.

Comment: Why you even need two textboxes ?

Comment: Well because it's different sections of the form, but both affect the same model property